# For loop on Django Template

Tags: python, django

I'm having a huge issue on making for loop on django templates,for some reasone it dont show on the page the categories that i create on database

urls.py

```
app_name = 'statenews'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name="home"),
path('', views.category, name = 'category'),]
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=65)
   ...

class News(models.Model):
   ...
category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
        default=None,
    )
```

views.py

```
def category(request):
categories = Category.objects.all()
return render(request,'partials/footer.html',{
    'categories': categories
})
```

html template

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-5">
        <h4 class="font-weight-bold mb-4">Tags</h4>
        {% for category in categories %}
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap m-n1">

            <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary m-1">({category.name})</a>

        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: If you don't tell what your issue is, solving it won't be easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two url paths with same url. Change it to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('categories', views.category, name = 'category')
]
```

Then enter via `yourdomain.com/categories`. Otherwise it will always show `home` view.

EDIT:

In you homepage you can simply see `home` view as it is set in `url` with `''`. If you want to see categories as footer part, then you have to change your `home` template, render it with `{% include 'partials/footer.html' %}`. Then you have to pass `categories` in `home` view context.

Comment: still dont show on my web page after the changes :/ 

i'm almost sure that the problem is in views

Comment: @CarlosEduardoVieiraMartins what url do you put into the browser?

Comment: it is on my homepage. i want to edit the footer to show the categories that i create on django/admin there.

Comment: In you homepage you can simply see `home` view as it is set in `url` with `''`. If you want to see categories as footer part, then you have to change your `home` template, render it with `{% include 'partials/footer.html' %}`. Then you have to pass `categories` in `home` view context.

Comment: If you want to see only the `categories` part, then you have to go to `localhost:8000/categories`, because only 1 view can be seen, whatever is first read.